# The css I add to the v-checkbox affects the css of the v-checkboxes on other pages

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I use a v-checkbox in tables on different pages in a vue js project.

**The css I used on the x page**

```
.v-input__slot {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.v-input--selection-controls {
  padding-left: 41%;
}
```

**The css I used on the y page**

```
.v-input__slot  {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.v-input--selection-controls {
  padding-left: 15%;
}
```

When I move from page x to page y, the css on page x stays on the y page. The same thing happens when I switch from page y to page x. How can I prevent this

[image: x table]

[image: y table]

The css 's of the X page are active on both pages.

Comment: Did you use `scoped` styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add keyword `scoped` in the `style` of your page so that you create a local style for your component. For example:

```
 <style scoped>
     .v-input__slot {
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
     }
     .v-input--selection-controls {
        padding-left: 41%;
     }
 </style>
```

You can read more about local and global style [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles)